# Move part of a Cocos2d project, into another project

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, project, particles

I'm from France so excuse my poor english.

So I have a project which don't use cocos 2d with a ball which is mooving, and I have another project but with cocos 2D where there are particles.

What I want to do is to bring the part of the cocos 2d project with particles into my real project with the ball.

First because I don't like the fact that my project is made with cocos 2d and second I have done everything on my real project and I must bring the particles.

How can I do this please?

Answer (score 0):

what i recommend you to do is to:

1. Create a new Cocos2d project from the templates
2. Open the project and drag the Cocos2d folder to your project

Now that you have the framework source code in there, it is just a matter of adding it to a viewcontroller that needs it. Check the AttachDemo test that comes with the Cocos2d examples to see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

what i recommend you to do is ,

1. Get the classes from the project to the real project
2. Import all the needed resources to the main project
3. Include the header files and the change the delegate class if needed.

i think this should do the job.